# Flow type for optional property on react component with attribute spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Having an interesting time trying to type the attributes on a react component using flow, where the attribute can be either an enum or a object.

It seems when I use a `{...spread}` for the attributes after an optional property that can have multiple type (union), flow always states they are incompatible.

The idea is to allow the attribute to be either a string value from an enum, or an object who's value's type has to be that enum as well.

It does work if the `{...spread}` is placed before the attribute, but that would not be desired functionality.

For example ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxkVHnJmAOR4XWMDcqqBAntqWAD6AFVIAPAgEEY6AOYA7MAF4mMUlAKMwAHyaVS8gqTxbdzOQAtNnbnwGiJ0uYpUjxUmQp1gA3mADaANakPABcYADOBHjo8rIAuuFujp6KAL42vPxgAAp02BHKvmBgRinOAPzhDh7OYGlclHDyUWAAwgDK0UUAFNj5EeF5cAUAlMoAfGAAPAAm6ABupe5OCkoARPqGxuu+AHQH-SMRaSXAEzbAwGBNLURtAPIARgBWvUcFQwPjSlNzi8tymsfH5BOFGFsjCZ6qcfAc9h8TmcLlwgA)):

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';

type _TextAlign = 'left' | 'center' | 'right';

type TextAlign = _TextAlign | { [key: string]: _TextAlign };

type Props = { textAlign?: TextAlign }

const CStr = (props: Props) => <div textAlign="center" {...props}  />;
```

Gives

```
8: type Props = {  textAlign?: TextAlign }
                               ^ object type [1] is incompatible with string [2].
```

Comment: I guess it's difficult to understand why you would want to set `textAlign = { 'a': 'right', 'b': 'center' }`. It looks like a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Look at some of the possible values of your `Props` type:

- `{ 'textAlign': 'left' }`
- `{ 'textAlign': { 'a': 'right', 'b': 'center' }`

So when you get to this part:

```
<div textAlign="center" {...props}  />;
```

you get an error because `{ 'a': 'right', 'b': 'center' }` is not a string, and not a valid value for `textAlign`.

You can build all the possible values into a type that has keys and values:

```
type TextAlign = { textAlign?: _TextAlign } | { [key: string]: _TextAlign };
type Props = { ...TextAlign };
```

But that is actually the same as:

```
type TextAlign = { [key: string]: _TextAlign };
type Props = { ...TextAlign };
```

There's no benefit in specifying the optional `'textAlign'` key if you then allow any other key too.

Comment: If I have to "build all the possible values into a type that has keys and values" - seems to mean I can't get my desired outcome of having a type that accepts either an or an object whose values are the enum?

Comment: @skh If `props` is a map with keys and string values then you can use the spread operator, as in your origins code. If the values are a mixture of strings and maps then you can't.

Comment: Are you expecting `{ 'textAlign' : { 'a': 'right', 'b': 'left' } }` to be a valid value of `Props`?

Comment: ideally, yes that would be valid